# Bitcoin wallet showing balance, Blockchain receiving address shows 0.00, wallet is from 2009 and hasn't been synced

Tags: blockchain, wallet

Old wallet, like from the first client, Has not been synced for at least 7 years. BTC balance shown, 0 pend, 0 available and blockchain address shows 0 balance. Still waiting for entire blockchain to sync but its passed the deposit date by years with no confirmations. 0.00 pending/avail am I boned?

Comment: It is incredibly unlikely you have a wallet from 2009, this predates transactions even using addresses for most transactions.

Comment: does a block explorer say no balance or there is balance?

Comment: Blockchain says 0.00 balance in address it was received on. Wallet shows balance with no confirmations. Transaction was in 2013, I sent myself coin from somewhere but cant really remember from where.

Answer (score 1):

If you can still log into the OLD wallet that has the BTC in it, you could try to set up a New Wallet under a different email address and then pay yourself. It will move the currency you have in that wallet to the new one.

You'll have to pay a fee though, unfortunately but if that's the only way to get it back and on a New Wallet where you can access the BTC again and have it synced up with the rest of the blockchain... that's what it may come down to.

If you're still having trouble let me know, I have an old wallet with scrap coin I'm gonna try a few things to see if it's been updated ever and see if I can send it to my new wallet.

Comment: Hi Robb, thanks for taking the time to answer techyguy's question. Please refrain from begging for money, we do not allow that here. Our site works a bit differently than a forum. Questions collect competing answers, they do not form threads. Please edit your prior answer to include more information rather than posting multiple answers. Check out our [tour] to get more info on how our site works.